# SQL sentence causes error when executed from Java/Spring Project

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, inner-join

In my current spring project, I have configured my spring-security xml filed with this SQL sentence for my UserDetailsService bean:

```
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select login, senha, enabled from usuario where login = ?"></property>
    <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT t1.username, t2.authority FROM (SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id) as t2 ON t1.credencial = t2.credencial WHERE t1.username = ?;"></property>
</bean>
```

the  SQL sentence:

```
SELECT t1.username, t2.authority
FROM (
    SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial
    FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c
    WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id
    ) as t1
        INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority
    FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a
    WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id
    ) as t2
        ON t1.credencial = t2.credencial
WHERE t1.username = ?;
```

is causing this error when I deploy and run the application on tomcat (the text below is from postgresql log file):

```
2018-01-26 07:53:41.644 -03 [20491] postgres@mydata ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER" at character 160
2018-01-26 07:53:41.644 -03 [20491] postgres@mydata STATEMENT:  (SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id) INNER JOIN (SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id)
2018-01-26 07:54:52.882 -03 [20491] postgres@mydata ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as" at character 160
2018-01-26 07:54:52.882 -03 [20491] postgres@mydata STATEMENT:  (SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id) as t2
2018-01-26 07:55:14.275 -03 [20491] postgres@mydata ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER" at character 158
2018-01-26 07:55:14.275 -03 [20491] postgres@mydata STATEMENT:  SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id INNER JOIN SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id
2018-01-26 07:56:55.362 -03 [20520] postgres@mydata ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as" at character 160
2018-01-26 07:56:55.362 -03 [20520] postgres@mydata STATEMENT:  (SELECT u.login as username, c.nome as credencial FROM usuario u, usuario_credencial uc, credencial c WHERE u.id = uc.usuario_id and c.id = uc.credenciais_id) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT c.nome as credencial, a.nome as authority FROM credencial c, credencial_autorizacao ca, autorizacao a WHERE c.id = ca.credencial_id and a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id) as t2 ON t1.credencial = t2.credencial
```

Anyone can give me a hint about what's causing this error?

Comment: Not causing the error specifically, but mixing the comma join and `JOIN` syntax makes it difficult to parse. At least for me.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using the ancient and outdated implicit joins inside the derived tables, but the modern explicit JOIN operator between them?

Comment: The query looks fine, does it work if you run it manually in a SQL client?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I run it in the pgAdmin3. Separately, the sentences execute without error. When I try the complete sentence (just copy and paste the code above, I get an error).

Comment: `credential` is part of both `SELECT`s, would consider having just one large join involving all 5 tables instead of having 2x3. Makes the whole query easier to read and understand.

Comment: adding to above given comments have you checked your join 3 tables are joined with 2 conditions dont know how they will work.Otherwise script looks ok to me. Try  CDATA

Comment: What if you remove `as` from the `) as t1` leaving just alias - `) t1`? And the same for the second `as`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, nver mind. I checked again and the full sentence is running without errors in the pgAdmin3; but when I copy and past in my xml file and deploy/run my application, I got the error in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Proposing a much simpler query:

```
SELECT u.login as username, a.nome as authority
FROM usuario u
JOIN usuario_credencial uc     ON u.id = uc.usuario_id
JOIN credencial c              ON c.id = uc.credenciais_id
JOIN credencial_autorizacao ca ON c.id = ca.credencial_id
JOIN autorizacao a             ON a.id = ca.autorizacoes_id
WHERE u.login = ?;
```